# Showing that an ideal is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I think that $k[x,y,z]/(z-1, x^2-y)$ can be identified as a subset of $k[x,y]$ with all polynomials whose $x$ terms are only degree one.

Therefore I conclude that $k[x,y,z]/(z-1, x^2-y)$ is integral domain and $(z-1, x^2-y)$ is a prime ideal. Could anyone tell me if this is a correct logic?

Here $k$ is a field.

Comment: In fact, $k[x,y,z]/(z-1,x^2-y)$ is isomorphic to $k[x]$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55246/is-y2-x-a-prime-ideal-in-fx-y